# Flash sound mixer stop all works on swf but not on html server version

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is a very strange bug! im using AS3 and CS5.

So i have a youtube video which plays on one frame, and on every other frame i have:

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

Which stops the video playing when you move to another page, this works fine when running it in flash, but when i publish it to a HTML file and upload it to my server it just never works! the sounds always play!
Is this to do with my publish settings or a strange flash bug? 
Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Thinking you may want to delete this question or just post the answer to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your SWF runs in the browser, it's subject to all the security restrictions that the browser imposes, as well as some additional Flash Player security restrictions. I imagine, that you're running into one of these restrictions.

Instead of trying to stop all sounds from playing, why don't you stop the Youtube player itself? It [has an API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#Playback_controls) you can use to do this, using either the `pauseVideo()` or `stopVideo()` methods.